# How can I fit a least absolute deviation model with random intercepts?

Tags: r, mixed-model, laplace-distribution, least-absolute-deviations, random-intercepts

I have some data and a model formulation that I believe describes the data generating process. The model looks like this

$$y_{i,t} = \beta_1x_{i,t} + \beta_2x_{i,t-1}+\alpha_t+\epsilon_{i,t}$$
where $\alpha_t$ is a random intercept associated with time $t$.

Both $\alpha$ and $\epsilon$ follow a Laplace distribution. I can get estimates for $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ from a least squares fit using `lme4::lmer` or similar. But least squares is equivalent to maximum likelihood over a normal distribution whilst maximum likelihood over a laplace distribution is equivalent to least absolute deviation.
If all else fails I can live with the resulting distorted standard errors but I would prefer to use a more appropriate fitting method.

I also tried to fit it in `stan` but after leaving it running overnight, it was still running in the morning.

Comment: You can use quantile regression.

Comment: @utobi thanks I am looking into that now for the first time. If you would like to elaborate on your rationale that would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know any reference for the case of $\alpha$ assumed to be Laplace, but if you are willing to assume that it is Gaussian, then this answer could be a solution.

[Least absolute deviations regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_absolute_deviations) turns out to be a particular case of [quantile regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_regression). In particular, the loss used in the least absolute deviations regression is proportional to the loss used in quantile regression when the parameter $\tau$ is fixed at 1/2.

Therefore, you could perform what you seek through mixed quantile regression machinery. Luckily this has been discussed in Geraci, M., Bottai, M. Linear quantile mixed models. *Stat Comput* **24**, 461–479 (2014). https://doi.org/10.1007/s11222-013-9381-9 and is implemented in the `R` package named [`lqmm`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lqmm/).